# User account status degraded?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

What does it mean when the user account status is "degraded"?  For instance, this is the case with the Guest account for my system.  Does this mean it is not active?

Thanks!

Edit: This can be seen by using WMIC to gather a list of user accounts.

```
wmic useraccount where (localaccount="TRUE") get caption,domain,name,fullname,sid,status /format:list > useraccounts.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system shows the same message, because the Guest Account is Disabled by default.

Enable the Guest account and it should change to Status=OK

Answer (score 1):

Degraded does not mean disabled!  You likely can't use the account in this state, but there it does not mean it is disabled.  If you have a default guest account such as in the question then yes, the degraded state is directly tied to the account being disabled.

[Win32_UserAccount class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394507(v=vs.85).aspx) states that the disabled status is a boolean.

You can have an account that is not disabled, but locked out.  This will equate to a disabled state.

I realize this may seem like a moot point as it functions as though it were disabled and it is effectively disabled.  This become important for activities such as audit and cleanup of users.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the Guest account is not currently enabled.